# I am creating a Django app .I am facing difficulty in the urls.py file. I want to use the path function not the url function

Tags: python, django

`path('apiemp/(?P<id>\d+)/$', views.EmployeeDetailsAll.as_view()),`

This is not working: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NxSmD.png)

But `url(r'^apiemp/(?P<id>\d+)/$` works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `path` function ([examples](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/urls/#example)) does not use regex. It uses [path converters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/urls/#path-converters) to capture any arguments needed. For your use you should write:

```
path('apiemp/<int:id>/', views.EmployeeDetailsAll.as_view()),
```